# problem in having one reference bold in .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, cross-referencing

I need to make just one of my references in my bib file, bold in the bibliography.
Here is my references:

```
@article{papike1982lunar,
  title={The lunar regolith: Chemistry, mineralogy, and petrology},
  author={Papike, JJ and Simon, S B\_ and Laul, JC},
  journal={Reviews of Geophysics},
  volume={20},
  number={4},
  pages={761--826},
  year={1982},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

If I add `\textbf` in the `{}`, nothing changed.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{aa}  

\usepackage{array}  
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            amsmath,  
            siunitx}  
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\title
\section
\bibliographystyle{aa} 
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

What should be changed to have this reference bold?

Comment: There is no `\bibliographystyle` called `aa` in my TeX distribution. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It is the docuement class of the journal template I need to submit my paper

Comment: Yes, but the name `aa` is not Google friendly. Is it this one http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/readme.html ?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes. It is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that works with `natbib` and the bibliography style you are using (and potentially others).

I defined a command `\makeboldref{⟨cite list⟩}` which adds each item in the `⟨cite list⟩` to a list of references to make bold. Later, when the list of references is being printed each citation key is checked against the ones in that list and made bold accordingly. You can use `\makeboldref` as many times as you need with as many keys as necessary. Each one will be added to the list of bold references.

Here's the output (I added another one to show the difference):

> [image]

And the code:

```latex
\documentclass{aa}  
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{papike1982lunar,
  title={The lunar regolith: Chemistry, mineralogy, and petrology},
  author={Papike, JJ and Simon, S B\_ and Laul, JC},
  journal={Reviews of Geophysics},
  volume={20},
  number={4},
  pages={761--826},
  year={1982},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@inproceedings {Gentleman1966,
address = {New York},
author = {Gentleman, W Morven and Sande, G},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the fall joint computer conference on XX - AFIPS '66},
doi = {10.1145/1464291.1464352},
pages = {563},
publisher = {ACM Press},
title = {{Fast Fourier Transforms---For Fun and Profit}},
url = {http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1464291.1464352},
year = {1966}}
\end{filecontents}

%%% Code to make bold references
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_yasamin_boldcite_seq
\cs_new_eq:NN \__yasamin_org_bibitem:wn \bibitem
\RenewDocumentCommand \bibitem { O{} m }
  {
    \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_yasamin_boldcite_seq {#2}
      { \__yasamin_boldify_bibitem:nnw {#1} {#2} }
      { \__yasamin_org_bibitem:wn [#1] {#2} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__yasamin_boldify_bibitem:nnw #1 #2 #3 \par
  {
    \__yasamin_org_bibitem:wn [#1] {#2}
    \group_begin:
      \bfseries #3 \tex_par:D
    \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \makeboldref { m }
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
    \seq_gconcat:NNN \g_yasamin_boldcite_seq \g_yasamin_boldcite_seq \l_tmpa_seq
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%% End of code


\usepackage{array}  
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            amsmath,  
            siunitx}  
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\title{aa}
\section{aa}

\cite{papike1982lunar,Gentleman1966}

\makeboldref{papike1982lunar} % <-- Adding to list of bold citations

\bibliographystyle{aa} 
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Shoul I add this code to the beginning of my main code?

Comment: @Yasamin You need to add everything from the `%%% Code to make bold references` until the `%%% End of code`, which is the commands I defined to make the item bold. After that use `\makeboldref` like in the example for each reference you want to make bold.

Comment: Great. It worked. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Yasamin I'm not asking you to change, I'm just curious. If this answer worked why did you mark the other one as “accepted”?

Comment: It was just a mistake by me. I am sorry. Your answer worked totally. I change it.

Comment: If I wan to make 3 or more references of my list bold, should I change something in the code? Because it seems that this code only make one reference bold.

Comment: @Yasamin No problem at all. I was just curious :-) To make more references bold you just need to add them to the command: `\makeboldref{papike1982lunar,anotherreference,onemore}`. Isn't it working?

Comment: worked now. Many thanks.

Comment: @Yasamin Good to know. I just noticed, there was a bug in the code, I fixed it now. The line that had `\seq_gconcat:NNN \g_yasamin_boldcite_seq \l_tmpa_seq` should be `\seq_gconcat:NNN \g_yasamin_boldcite_seq \g_yasamin_boldcite_seq \l_tmpa_seq`. Please fix it in your document to avoid problems. Now you should be able to use `\makeboldref{papike1982lunar,anotherreference,onemore}` (comma-separated) and `\makeboldref{papike1982lunar}` then `\makeboldref{onemore}` at your option.

Comment: I fix it now and it worked good. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to switch to using `biblatex`, you can achieve this fairly easily using bibliography categories:

```
% define a new bibliography category
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{boldcitations} 

% list of citations to make bold
\addtocategory{boldcitations}{papike1982lunar,SomeOtherPaper} 

% sort-of ugly hack to make the citation bold:
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \ifcategory{boldcitations}
      {\bfseries}
      {}}
```

Full document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{boldcitations} % define a new bibliography category

\addtocategory{boldcitations}{papike1982lunar,SomeOtherPaper} % list of citations to make bold

\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \ifcategory{boldcitations}
      {\bfseries} % ugly hack to make the citation bold
      {}}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents} % just for demonstration

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@inproceedings{TestDoe,
    title={This is a Test},
    author={Doe, Jane and Roe, John},
    booktitle={2016 Placeholder Conference on Citation Testing},
    pages={1--2},
    year={2016}
}

@inproceedings{TestSmith,
    title={This is also a Test},
    author={Smith, John and Jones, Ben},
    booktitle={2016 Placeholder Conference on Citation Testing},
    pages={3--4},
    year={2016}
}

@article{papike1982lunar,
  title={The lunar regolith: Chemistry, mineralogy, and petrology},
  author={Papike, JJ and Simon, S B\_ and Laul, JC},
  journal={Reviews of Geophysics},
  volume={20},
  number={4},
  pages={761--826},
  year={1982},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document} 

\cite{papike1982lunar}, \cite{TestSmith},\cite{TestDoe}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But is there anyway to not switcing to biblatex? Because by adding these codes I get tons of erros. It seems it makes everything different and I can not fix the errors as a beginner.

Comment: @Yasamin If you need to use a specific template/document class that doesn't support biblatex (like your `aa`, which turns out to use natbib), see Phelype's answer. This one's more of an alternative for people who do have a choice.