Colouring a citation in the bibliography via \cite
I have the following command that colours a block of text in revised versions of my paper:
\newcommand{\revnum}{1}  % which revision are we currently working on (we can change this for later revisions)
\newcommand{\revcolour}{green}  % colour of revised text
\newif\ifrev  % so we can know if we're in a revision inside other constructs

\newcommand{\rev}[2][1]{% Optional argument has default value 1 so we can just use \rev for the first revision and then \rev[2], \rev[3], etc. for future ones
    \ifnum#1<\revnum%
        #2%
    \else%
        \revtrue%
        \textcolor{\revcolour}{#2}%
        \revfalse%
    \fi%
}

This works fine throughout the text, but I don't know how to use it to colour an entry in the bibliography. I defined another command \revcite:
\newcommand{\revcite}[2][1]{{%
    \ifnum#1<\revnum%
    \else%
        \hypersetup{citecolor=\revcolour}%
    \fi%
    \rev[#1]{\cite{#2}}%
}}

This command properly colours citations in the text (both the citation brackets and the actual hyperlink), but it doesn't change the colour of the corresponding text in the bibliography list. Ideally, I would like to make the colouring of the cited reference part of this command so that the user only has to use the \revcite command and all the colouring is handled automatically. If this is not possible, I would settle for any way to colour specific entries in the bibliography.
I use bibtex, usually in conjunction with the natbib package, although if possible, I'd like the solution to work with or without the natbib package.
MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\revnum}{1}  % which revision are we currently working on (we can change this for later revisions)
\newcommand{\revcolour}{blue}  % colour of revised text
\newif\ifrev  % so we can know if we're in a revision inside other constructs

\newcommand{\rev}[2][1]{% Optional argument has default value 1 so we can just use \rev for the first revision and then \rev[2], \rev[3], etc. for future ones
    \ifnum#1<\revnum%
        #2%
    \else%
        \revtrue%
        \textcolor{\revcolour}{#2}%
        \revfalse%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\revcite}[2][1]{{%
    \ifnum#1<\revnum%
    \else%
        \hypersetup{citecolor=\revcolour}%
    \fi%
    \rev[#1]{\cite{#2}}%
}}

\begin{document}

This text should be normal. \rev{But this should be blue.} Also this should be normal colour but the reference should be blue \revcite{a}. However, this reference should be normal \cite{b}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Literature}

\end{document}

And Literature.bib contains:
@article{a,
    author={Made up author},
    title={This whole citation should also be blue},
}

@article{b,
    author={Made up author},
    title={But this one shouldn't be}
}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I've editted in a MWE.

You could use the same approach as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491194/36296 :
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
    
    author={Made up author},
    title={This whole citation should also be blue},
}

@article{b,
    author={Made up author},
    title={But this one shouldn't be}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\revnum}{1}  % which revision are we currently working on (we can change this for later revisions)
\newcommand{\revcolour}{blue}  % colour of revised text
\newif\ifrev  % so we can know if we're in a revision inside other constructs

\newcommand{\rev}[2][1]{% Optional argument has default value 1 so we can just use \rev for the first revision and then \rev[2], \rev[3], etc. for future ones
    \ifnum#1<\revnum%
        #2%
    \else%
        \revtrue%
        \textcolor{\revcolour}{#2}%
        \revfalse%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\revcite}[2][1]{{%
    \ifnum#1<\revnum%
    \else%
        \hypersetup{citecolor=\revcolour}%
    \fi%
    \rev[#1]{\cite{#2}}%
    \makeblueref{#2}%
}}

%%% Code to make blue references
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_yasamin_bluecite_seq
\cs_new_eq:NN \__yasamin_org_bibitem:wn \bibitem
\RenewDocumentCommand \bibitem { O{} m }
  {
    \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_yasamin_bluecite_seq {#2}
      { \__yasamin_blueify_bibitem:nnw {#1} {#2} }
      { \__yasamin_org_bibitem:wn [#1] {#2} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__yasamin_blueify_bibitem:nnw #1 #2 #3 \par
  {
    \__yasamin_org_bibitem:wn [#1] {#2}
    \group_begin:
      \color{blue} #3 \tex_par:D
    \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \makeblueref { m }
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
    \seq_gconcat:NNN \g_yasamin_bluecite_seq \g_yasamin_bluecite_seq \l_tmpa_seq
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%% End of code

\begin{document}



This text should be normal. \rev{But this should be blue.} Also this should be normal colour but the reference should be blue \revcite{a}. However, this reference should be normal \cite{b}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}


